# How can I split scraped data and save it in separate columns as csv with full link and description?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im working on a Web Scraper which is returning the links and descriptions of job postings if it matches the list of keywords. The issue I have is that the csv thats being exported is just one long sentence where the link and the description go into one line.

How can I effectively split the the description and links into two separate columns? And how can I add the remainder of the link in order to be able to click the link inside of the csv? Also is there a way of avoiding duplicate entries in the csv?

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time, re, csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

keywords = ["KI", "AI", "Big Data", "Data", "data", "big data", 
"Analytics", "analytics", "digitalisierung", "ML",
"Machine Learning", "Daten", "Datenexperte", 
"Datensicherheitsexperte", "Analytikleistungen"]

browser = webdriver.Chrome()

url = "https://ausschreibungen.usp.gv.at/at.gv.bmdw.eproc-p/public"

browser.implicitly_wait(30)

browser.get(url)


innerHTML = browser.execute_script("return 
document.body.innerHTML")

soup = BS(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')

# browser.quit()
# print(soup.text)
tenders = soup.find('table', {'id': 'tenderlist'})
tbody = tenders.find('tbody')

browser.quit()


ausschreiben_found = []

for tr in tbody.find_all('tr'):
    ausschreiben = tr.find_all('td')
for keyword in keywords:
    for word in ausschreiben:
        if keyword in str(word):
            ausschreiben_found.append(word)
            print(ausschreiben_found)
with open("ausschreiben.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as toWrite:
    fieldnames = ["Beschreibung", "Links"]
    writer = csv.writer(toWrite)
    writer.writerows(ausschreiben_found)
    # subprocess.call('./Autopilot3.py')
    print("Matched Ausschreiben have been collected.")
```

Comment: when I run your code, it produces an empty list for ausschreiben_found (or I should say, nothing gets appended).

Comment: I'd also like to add you can access the table through the XHR found when you inspect the page

Comment: If nothing gets appended, does that not mean there were no matches? The other day it returned 2 listings, or am I wrong? Could you elaborate on XHR?

Comment: When you look at the Ajax requests this page sends, there is one that fills the data table (`.../at.gv.bmdw.eproc-p/ajax/dataTablesTenderList?...`). It returns JSON. You might have a much easier time requesting this directly than going though Selenium and trying to parse the HTML.

Comment: Erik, you are correct, that if nothing was appended, that means nothing was found with those keywords.  I was anticipating since you posted it today, you were getting results today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the website uses Ajax and a JavaScript library to fill the table on the page, the easiest way to to grab the data you want is to replicate the Ajax request.

The JSON data from the server has this structure:

```
{
    "value": {
        "draw": "-1",
        "recordsTotal": 1476,
        "recordsFiltered": 1476,
        "data": [{
            "DT_RowClass": "even",
            "0": "<a href=\"/at.gv.bmdw.eproc-p/public/de_AT/tenderlist?action=view&amp;object=41a809d9-0b61-4991-86b8-74dc07973af3-15ed14df-d91c-4905-94fd-e1d7935eaef1\">Planung Freiland/Brücke</a>",
            "1": "Autobahnen- und Schnellstraßen-Finanzierungs-Aktiengesellschaft",
            "2": "08.04.2019",
            "3": null
        }, {
            "DT_RowClass": "odd",
            "0": "<a href=\"/at.gv.bmdw.eproc-p/public/de_AT/tenderlist?action=view&amp;object=86dd87bd-7426-40c5-946b-62b2af638aab-7a54478b-9e89-4d47-bdf8-dc8b867c57b8\">Lieferung von Erdgas 2020 - 2022</a>",
            "1": "Republik Österreich (Bund), Bundesbeschaffung GmbH sowie alle weiteren Auftraggeber gemäß der den Ausschreibungsunterlagen beiliegenden Drittkundenliste, im Vergabeverfahren alle vertreten durch die Bundesbeschaffung GmbH",
            "2": "08.04.2019",
            "3": "07.05.2019"
        }]
    }
}
```

The following uses the `requests` module to fetch the JSON from the server and the littelest HTML parser to extract the text from the links. You are free to use BeautifulSoup for the same purpose.

```
import requests
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class TinyTextExtractor(HTMLParser):
    def parse(self, html):
        self.text = ''
        self.feed(html)
        return self.text

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.text += data

def get_ausschreibungen(start=0, length=25):
    url = 'https://ausschreibungen.usp.gv.at/at.gv.bmdw.eproc-p/ajax/dataTablesTenderList'
    resp = requests.get(url, {
        'start': start,
        'length': length
    })

    parser = TinyTextExtractor()

    for row in resp.json()['value']['data']:
        yield {
            'Bezeichnung': parser.parse(row['0']),
            'Organisation': row['1'],
            'Veröffentlicht':  row['2'],
            'Frist': row['3'],
        }
```

Usage:

```
for item in get_ausschreibungen(0, 3):
    print(item)
```

Which prints this for me:

```
{'Bezeichnung': 'Planung Freiland/Brücke', 'Organisation': 'Autobahnen- und Schnellstraßen-Finanzierungs-Aktiengesellschaft', 'Veröffentlicht': '08.04.2019', 'Frist': None}
{'Bezeichnung': 'Lieferung von Erdgas 2020 - 2022', 'Organisation': 'Republik Österreich (Bund), Bundesbeschaffung GmbH sowie alle weiteren Auftraggeber gemäß der den Ausschreibungsunterlagen beiliegenden Drittkundenliste, im Vergabeverfahren alle vertreten durch die Bundesbeschaffung GmbH', 'Veröffentlicht': '08.04.2019', 'Frist': '07.05.2019'}
{'Bezeichnung': 'Umbau Bahnhof Villach ', 'Organisation': 'ÖBB-Personenverkehr AG', 'Veröffentlicht': '08.04.2019', 'Frist': None}
```

I'm sure that filtering/turning it into CSV is not a problem anymore.

Use the browser's developer tools (F12) to figure out what other request parameters are being sent and if they are relevant to you. You could also try "blending in" using the Session feature of the `requests` module, replicating all the HTTP headers and cookies, but given that this appears to be a government site, they probably won't mind that you are scraping them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Did not realise I could use the Ajax request to parse the data from :)

Comment: Is there a way to parse the href link as well?

Comment: As I said, you can use BeautifulSoup for parsing the string at `row['0']`. Since there could be more complex HTML in the first column than just a singular `<a>`, that's a good idea anyway.

Comment: There also is a way to extend my "littlelest HTML parser" for that, if you fancy a challenge, you can try doing that (read up on [the `html.parser` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), hint: you need to write a `handle_starttag` method). The reward would be that it's probably a bit faster than the heavier BeautifulSoup, and that you learn how to work with event-based parsers. :)

Answer (score 0):

to write in separate columns

```py
reader = csv.DictReader(f) # open and write mode opened file
csvWriter = csv.writer(f)
existing_queries = set()
for row in reader:
    if reader.line_num == 1:
       continue
if row['link'] in existing_queries:
    print("Already exists")
else:
    csvWriter.writerow("description", "link") # will write
    existing_queries.add("description", "link")
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Use the newline and delimiter parameters of the csv.writer Class

You can find examples here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects

Comment: While this may help OP, it's better to add more details, examples, etc.  Please [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)